# PDF link goes to "Cannot GET file" with a 404 error

Tags: html, pdf, href

Trying to have a link open up to a PDF. I have the href="filename.pdf" - the pdf file is in the same folder as the html file. When I click on the link it opens to a new page (I have it set to open a new page) which says "Cannot GET /filename.pdf". I open the console and it says "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)".

I found a solution that works but I don't understand why:
This doesn't work:

```
<a target="_blank" class="cta-btn cta-btn--resume" href="connerschiller.pdf">View Resume</a>
```

But this does work:

```
<a target="_blank" class="cta-btn cta-btn--resume" href="../src/connerschiller.pdf">View Resume</a>
```

The html file is in the src folder as well.

Ok so the fix I listed above is working when I run it locally, but when I try to open the PDF link on the deployed site on netlify it says "Page Not Found
Looks like you've followed a broken link or entered a URL that doesn't exist on this site."

Comment: Could you please add some code?

Comment: Well I sort of found an answer...I had to move back out of the folder, go back into the same folder, and then it worked. That just doesn't make sense to me, but I'll try to add the line of code to my question.

Comment: do you may have a src folder and another like "build" where the html is? I think the problem is not in your markup but on the file structure

Answer (score 0):

If the file is in the same directory you need to use as follows:

```
<a href="./filename.pdf">My pdf</a>
```

the ./ is to especify the same directory